# ViewPager Fragment scenario where the Fragment need to handle on/off status

Tags: android, android-viewpager, visibility

I have this `ViewPager` that has 5 `Fragment` and I set the `setOffscreenPageLimit(4)`. Now when app start all five `Fragments` are loaded.

In `Fragment` nr 4 I want to start a `Handler` with a delay that every sec show some data. I only want to start it when user select that Fragment Tab and stop the 'Handler' when user go to another tab.

I could not find a straight good way to do this.

I use the [greenrobot.eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to make this work since I know when a `ViewPager` page is changed to `Fragment` nr 4. I can just send an event to `Fragment` nr 4.

But this is ugly I think!

Since the Fragment is loaded only once I cant use the `onAttached()` To start a `Handler` and `onDetached()` To stop `Handler`

I created a 'getViewTreeObserver' for one of the 'TextViews' on the 'Fragment' and when 'onGlobalLayout()' fire the 'getVisibility()' is always 'View.VISIBLE' even I go to other tabs in the 'ViewPager'

What other options do I have?

Here´s what I have and it´s working by using the [greenrobot.eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and the `Fragment` is a `PreferenceFragmentCompat` with this custom `Preference`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.sunlux.smartpower.extended.R;
import com.sunlux.smartpower.extended.entity.EventOnViewPgaerTabChange;
import com.sunlux.smartpower.extended.utils.SettingsManager;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode;

public class ShowStatPreference extends Preference {

    private long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;
    private TextView bytesStat;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean statRunning;
    /**
     * Timer for updating stat
     */
    private final Runnable statRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setStatBytes();
            if (statRunning) {
                startStatTimer();
            }
        }
    };

    public ShowStatPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ShowStatPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ShowStatPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.show_stat_preference);
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setClickable(false); // disable parent click
        bytesStat = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.bytes);
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
    }

    private void startStatTimer() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(statRunnable, 1000);
    }

    private void setStatBytes() {
        long bytes = Long.parseLong(SettingsManager.getByteSent());
        long mb = bytes / MEGABYTE;
        bytesStat.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.total_bytes, Long.toString(bytes), Long.toString(mb)));
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void workStart(EventOnViewPgaerTabChange event) {
        if (event.pos == 4) {
            if(statRunning){
                // prevent duplicate start
                return;
            }
            statRunning = true;
            startStatTimer();
        } else {
            statRunning = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttached() {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        super.onAttached();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetached() {
        super.onDetached();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

There are many questions about this but since I dont want to access the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` but rather the `Preference` inside of it, I have tried to propagate a method call from `PreferenceFragmentCompat` like this

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
       // call Preference class ShowStatPreference and start the Handler

}
```

But cant find a way to access the inner class of `PreferenceFragmentCompat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
ShowStatPreference myStat = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key_show_stat)) as ShowStatPreference
```